# Email forwarding - set with domain register or hosting company

Tags: email, domains, registration

I have registered a domain with one company (1&1) and am hosting the site with another company (GoDaddy).

I want all emails sent to anything@mydomain.com forwarded to my personal email. So my question is, do I set up the forwarder with the registrar or the hoster?

Also if changing MX records are involved - which end should I change them at? (I notice that both companies have the facility to edit them but they seem to be set to different values at each.)

Also, the website has a PHP mailer to allow visitors to send me emails - which I need to keep working.

(I have tried setting it up at the registrar but it doenst work, though they say I may have to wait 48 hours to know for sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing web hosting with email hosting. The company that hosts your website, while they are usually your email host as well, aren't always. Have you configured email hosting for your domain yet? If you haven't easiest way would be with your web host as chances are it is included with your hosting plan. If they are hosting your DNS as well it is quite possible that they have already set-up email hosting for you without you explicitly requesting it, in which case you can easily set-up an email forwarder from the hosting panel, your hosting company will be able to help you out on the steps for this with their hosting panel system.

Either way while many registrar's act as web hosting companies as well you do not have to use them for your hosting as well. You can split all your hosting so that domain name is registered with one registrar, DNS is hosted by another company, website is hosted by a third, and emails hosted by a fourth, more complicated and can be more expensive but the point I am trying to make is that the nature of the internet is that any part of your online presence can be hosted by different entities.

Comment: I recommend for people who are not familiar with all this stuff is to find one high quality company that can handle all of what a person would need; domain registration, site hosting, e-mail, certificates, e-commerce, etc. Otherwise, they will easily get confused and get the run-around. Even straightening out DNS entries with separate hosting can seriously confuse a novice. We get that here a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that your registrar will be able to do this as most registrars do not include DNS with a domain registration - unless they also do hosting and will likely charge you extra $$ for that.

The nameservers for your domain will point somewhere, likely to your hosting company, that is the where you should set up things if you can, assuming they offer services such as email - services like SquareSpace don't I don't think.

Since you seem to be struggling with how to do all this, it is better to keep it as simple as possible. If your nameservers are pointing to your webhost then you won't have to change A records (for website) or MX records (for email).